# How to get Stream<QuerySnapshot> from nested collections Flutter/Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform

I want to provide to a StreamProvider.value the Snapshots of a nested collection inside my firestore.

I have the following Structure in firestore:

- Root:

  - User (Collection)

    - User1 (Document with fields)
    - User2 (Document with fields)
  - Orders (Collection)

    - Order1 (Document with fields)

      - Products (Collection)

        - Meal1 (Document with fields)
        - Meal2 (Document with fields)
      - Date

I would like to obtain a Stream of the Products for a specified order because I want to notify changes to my app only for that order.

This is my current code (I have one order each day and I want the stream of products of the current day's order):

```
class DatabaseService {

  final CollectionReference _collOrders =
      Firestore.instance.collection("orders");

  Future<DocumentSnapshot> _getTodayOrder(DateTime date) async {
    QuerySnapshot lastOrder = await _collOrders.getDocuments();
    for (DocumentSnapshot orderData in lastOrder.documents) {
      var dateOrder = DateTime.parse(orderData.data["Date"]);
      int diffDays = date.difference(dateOrder).inDays;
      if (diffDays == 0) 
      { 
        return orderData ;
      }
    }
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getStreamOrdersByDay(DateTime date) {
    _getTodayOrder(date).then((value) {
      return value.reference.collection("Products").snapshots();
    });
  }
}
```

And in my homePage:

```
...

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>.value(
      value: DatabaseService().getStreamOrdersByDay(DateTime.now()),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("APiZZa")),
        body: Container(...)
...
```

But when I call:

```
final orders = Provider.of<QuerySnapshot>(context);
```

from a child widget, "orders" is null. I think that flutter is building the homepage without waiting for _getTodayOrder to finish. What do you suggest to do?

Comment: Did you happen to get this working? I also have similar requirement